# Create a custom month that starts at day x

Tags: python, pandas

From my date column I want to create another one with the months. But I would like create a specific range. For exammple `Jan` will be from `2020-01-03` to `2020-02-03`. `Feb` will be from `20-02-03` to `20-03-03` and so on.

This is my df:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
#Start of the calendar
start='2020-01-01'
#End of the calendar
end='2020-12-31'
#Create the calendar df
cal_df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": pd.date_range(start, end)})
#Extract the day
cal_df['Day'] = cal_df['Date'].dt.day
#Extract the day name
cal_df['Day_name'] =cal_df[['Date']].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x['Date'], '%A'), axis=1)
```

I tried to use the if statement but does not behave like I want.

```
start = '2020-01-03'
end_date = '2020-02-03'
if  [(cal_df['Date'] > start) & (cal_df['Date'] <= end_date)]:
    cal_df['Month'] = 'Jan'
else:
    cal_df['Month'] = ' others'
```

So the above code puts `Jan` everywhere even if  `Date` is les than the specified `end_date`.

Can someone tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: kindly post ur expected output

Comment: Subtract the dates by 3 days and extract the month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with helper groups compared next day, `4` with [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for months:

```
m = cal_df['Date'].dt.strftime('%b')
g = cal_df['Day'].eq(4).cumsum()

cal_df['Month'] = m.groupby(g).transform('first')
```

Or idea from comments - subtract 3 days, but first values are `Dec`:

```
cal_df['Month1'] = cal_df['Date'].sub(pd.Timedelta(3, 'd')).dt.strftime('%b')
```

So you can change solution by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and back filling missing values:

```
s = cal_df['Date'].sub(pd.Timedelta(3, 'd'))
cal_df['Month2'] =  s.where(s > cal_df['Date'].min()).bfill().dt.strftime('%b')
```

---

```
m = cal_df['Date'].dt.strftime('%b')
g = cal_df['Day'].eq(4).cumsum()

cal_df['Month'] = m.groupby(g).transform('first')

cal_df['Month1'] = cal_df['Date'].sub(pd.Timedelta(3, 'd')).dt.strftime('%b')

s = cal_df['Date'].sub(pd.Timedelta(3, 'd'))
cal_df['Month2'] =  s.where(s > cal_df['Date'].min()).bfill().dt.strftime('%b')

print (cal_df.head(10))
        Date  Day   Day_name Month Month1 Month2
0 2020-01-01    1  Wednesday   Jan    Dec    Jan
1 2020-01-02    2   Thursday   Jan    Dec    Jan
2 2020-01-03    3     Friday   Jan    Dec    Jan
3 2020-01-04    4   Saturday   Jan    Jan    Jan
4 2020-01-05    5     Sunday   Jan    Jan    Jan
5 2020-01-06    6     Monday   Jan    Jan    Jan
6 2020-01-07    7    Tuesday   Jan    Jan    Jan
7 2020-01-08    8  Wednesday   Jan    Jan    Jan
8 2020-01-09    9   Thursday   Jan    Jan    Jan
9 2020-01-10   10     Friday   Jan    Jan    Jan
```

Comment: This is very smart. Thank you @jezrael